# Problemas $scope mdDialog angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, dialog

Bom dia galera!

Estou com problemas ao passar um array para um md-dialog.

Ao clicar em um botão editar é enviado o array que está no $scope via locals para o controller do md-dialog, para que eu possa fazer alteração dos dados e salvá-los. Mas o problema é que toda a modificação que eu faço no array dentro do md-dialog é aplicada simultaneamente no array da pagina que está "atrás" do dialogo(página que enviou os dados), mesmo se eu cancelar o diálogo.

Por exemplo: Eu passo o array com várias linhas para o dialog, e se eu remover uma linha do array lá neste dialog ele também remove a linha do array da página de envio. Parece que eles estão vinculados e tudo que acontece em um se repete no outro mesmo se eu cancelar o diálogo. Dai quando eu volto no editar array está sem a linha que foi excluída antes mesmo tendo cancelado o dialog.

Agradeço desde já quem ajudar.

Abraço!

Comment: É possível compartilhar o código referente ao seu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, eles estão ligados, é uma feature do AngularJS, é a raiz do modo como ele funciona, o MVVM.

Se você quer fazer modificações no seu array dentro do escopo do md-dialog e se esse array precisa ser igual ao do escopo pai, você pode usar o `angular.copy()` para criar uma cópia do array e passar ele para o md-dialog.

Comment: Perfeito Juan!! Não fazia ideia da existência deste comando. Estou começando com o angular e me ajudou muito aqui. Obrigado mesmo. Grande abraço!